# Show popup on the map for the selected item in the side list using the mapbox gl js

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I followed this tutorial ["Filter features within map view"](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/filter-features-within-map-view/) and managed to adapt it to my data, which are polygons instead of points.

However, the popups on the side menu are not displayed, when I place the mouse over one of the locations, the popup does not appear on the map indicating the location as it should.
The problem I believe is that because it is a polygon and not a point (a pair of coordinates) the code cannot display the location, the error in the console is:

```
"Uncaught Error:` LngLatLike` argument must be specified as a LngLat instance, an object {lng: <lng>, lat: <lat>}, an object {lon: <lng>, lat: <lat>}, or an array of [<lng>, <lat>] "
```

In the map popup I changed it from "`.setLngLat (feature.geometry.coordinates)`"
to "`.setLngLat (e.lngLat)`" and it worked, but not in the popup on the side menu.
I'm still starting to learn javascript and I couldn't find a solution, I thought about extracting the centroid from the polygon, but I don't know how to do it.

the code that generates the popup:

```
var prop = feature.properties;
var item = document.createElement('a');
item.href = prop.wikipedia;
item.target = '_blank';
item.textContent = prop.NM_UF + ' (' + prop.SIGLA_UF + ')';
item.addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
    // Highlight corresponding feature on the map
    popup
        .setLngLat(feature.geometry.coordinates)
        .setText(
            feature.properties.NM_UF +
            ' (' +
            feature.properties.SIGLA_UF +
            ')'
        )
        .addTo(map);
});
listingEl.appendChild(item);
    });
```

Here is a codepen like the code:
https://codepen.io/hugonbgg/pen/PoNwWVj and the debug: https://codepen.io/hugonbgg/debug/PoNwWVj/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long story short, you are using a source that includes `Polygon` and `MultiPolygon` features together, so your selected feature coordinates is sometimes an array and sometimes a multidimensional array.

There are different ways to solve this...

**Quick and dirty**

```js
popup
    .setLngLat(feature.geometry.coordinates[0][0]) //just add [0][0]
    .setText(
        feature.properties.NM_UF +
        ' (' +
        feature.properties.SIGLA_UF +
        ')'
    )
    .addTo(map);
```

This just works but positions the popup tip on the first point of the first polygon... not definitely the best but it works.

The second method is what I would do...

**Find the center of any feature through a method**

I have created this [codepen](https://codepen.io/jscastro76/pen/jOqELjN) based on yours with this change to include a `getFeatureCenter` method.

```js
function getFeatureCenter(feature) {
    let center = [];
    let latitude = 0;
    let longitude = 0;
    let height = 0;
    let coordinates = [];
    feature.geometry.coordinates.forEach(function (c) {
        let dupe = [];
        if (feature.geometry.type === "MultiPolygon")
            dupe.push(...c[0]); //deep clone to avoid modifying the original array
        else 
            dupe.push(...c); //deep clone to avoid modifying the original array
        dupe.splice(-1, 1); //features in mapbox repeat the first coordinates at the end. We remove it.
        coordinates = coordinates.concat(dupe);
    });
    if (feature.geometry.type === "Point") {
        center = coordinates[0];
    }
    else {
        coordinates.forEach(function (c) {
            latitude += c[0];
            longitude += c[1];
        });
        center = [latitude / coordinates.length, longitude / coordinates.length];
    }

    return center;
}
```

and then change in your call to the popup

```js
popup
    .setLngLat(getFeatureCenter(feature)) //call the new method and enjoy!
    .setText(
        feature.properties.NM_UF +
        ' (' +
        feature.properties.SIGLA_UF +
        ')'
    )
    .addTo(map);
```

This will find the feature center independently if it is `Point`, `Polygon` or `MultiPolygon`...

[image]

PS.- If this answer solves your question, please mark it as **"answer accepted"**, in that way will also help other users to know it was the right solution.

Comment: It worked! Your answer served as an inspiration to solve it in another way, in QGIS I calculated the centroid of the polygons and saved them in columns X and Y. Then I loaded them in a variable: 
var X = feature.properties.X;
var Y = feature.properties.Y;
coordinates = [X, Y]

Comment: Glad if I could be of any help!